# Accessing data attributes with dataset JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dataset, custom-data-attribute

I'm having an issue around accessing the values in my data attributes.

- I currently have a button, which has a set of data attributes.
- I'm looking to access the values in these attributes via dataset in my script file.
- Once accessed, change to json.

I know it's something small I'm missing but I've been staring at it for so long that I just can't see it now. I think I'm missing a line a code within the getDataAttributes function, just after getElementById but can't figure out what it is.

Thanks in advance!

jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/robgit28/4y165bsf/1/

HTML

```
<button type='button' id="addtowebsite"> 
    <div class="add-btn"
         data-userid="123"
         data-firstname="John"
         data-lastname="Doe">Add button
    </div>
</button>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
document.getElementById('addtowebsite').addEventListener("click", function () {
    getDataAttributes(this);
    });
    
    function getDataAttributes(input) {
        var select = document.getElementById('addtowebsite');
        var jsonData = JSON.stringify({
            userId: parseInt(input.dataset.userid), 
            firstName: input.dataset.firstname,
            lastName: input.dataset.hostlastname,
            });
            return jsonData;
                    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <button type='button' id="addtowebsite"> 
        <div id="d"
             class="add-btn"
             data-userid="123"
             data-firstname="John"
             data-lastname="Doe">Add button
        </div>
    </button>
```

```js
document.getElementById('addtowebsite').addEventListener("click", function () {
    getDataAttributes(this);
    });
    
    function getDataAttributes(input) {
        var select = document.getElementById("d");
        var jsonData = JSON.stringify({
            userId : parseInt(select.getAttribute("data-userid")), 
            firstName : select.getAttribute("data-firstname"),
            lastName : select.getAttribute("data-lastName"),
            });
            return jsonData;
                    }
```

```html
        <button type='button' id="addtowebsite"> 
            <div id="d"
                 class="add-btn"
                 data-userid="123"
                 data-firstname="John"
                 data-lastname="Doe">Add button
            </div>
        </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks hamed! Was so silly! I saw the mistake in my code and then came back to see your answer - thanks!

I simply did this...

```
<button type='button' id="addtowebsite"> 
    <div class="add-btn" id="div"
         data-userid="123"
         data-firstname="John"
         data-lastname="Doe">Add button
    </div>
</button>

<script>
var input = document.getElementById('div'); 
    
    function getDataAttributes() {
        var jsonData = JSON.stringify({
            userId: parseInt(input.dataset.userid), 
            firstName: input.dataset.firstname,
            lastName: input.dataset.hostlastname,
            });
            console.log(jsonData);
            return jsonData;
                    } 
</script>
```