# How to get option tag custom data value using pure JS?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function calculateDeliveryCharge()
 {
     var CA=document.getElementById("pickup");
     var c=CA.options[CA.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-area');

    alert(c);
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
         <div class="col-12">
            <select id="pickup" placeholder="পিকআপ এলাকা নির্বাচন করুন">
              <option value="">পিকআপ এলাকা.....</option>
              <option value="300 Feet"data-area="1">৩০০ ফিট (300 Feet)</option>
              <option value="Adabor" data-area="1">আদাবর(Adabor)</option>
              <option value="Adarsha Nagar(Badda)"data-area="1">আদর্শ নগর(বাড্ডা)- Adarsha Nagar(Badda)</option>
              <option value="Aftab Nagar"data-area="1">আফতাব নগর(Aftab Nagar)</option>
              <option value="Aga Nagar"data-area="1">আগা নগর(Aga Nagar)</option>
              <option value="Agargaon"data-area="1">আগারগাঁও(Agargaon)</option>
              <option value="Ahalia-Uttara"data-area="1">আহালিয়া-উত্তরা(Ahalia-Uttara)</option>
              <option value="Ahmed Nagar"data-area="1">আহমেদ নগর(Ahmed Nagar)</option>
              <option value="Ainusbag"data-area="1">আইনুসবাগ(Ainusbag)</option>
              <option value="Ainusbag-Dakshinkhan"data-area="1">আইনুসবাগ-দক্ষিণখান(Ainusbag-Dakshinkhan)</option>
              <option value="Ajiz Market"data-area="1">আজিজ মার্কেট(Ajiz Market)</option>
              <option value="Alatunnessa School Road"data-area="1">আলাতুন্নেছা স্কুল রোড(Alatunnessa School Road)</option>
              <option value="Alubazar"data-area="1">আলুবাজার(Alubazar)</option>
              <option value="Amin bazar"data-area="1">আমিন বাজার(Amin bazar)</option>
              <option value="Apollo"data-area="1">অ্যাপোলো(Apollo)</option>

            </select>
         </div>
     </div>
     <button class="border-1 p-2 bg-danger text-white"onclick="calculateDeliveryCharge()">ডেলিভারি চার্জ দেখুন</button>

</div>
```

I want to get the custom data attribute "data-area" value, 1 expected is here but I am getting null every time. What is the problem in my code and what is the solution?

Comment: Your code works. I can't replicate your problem.

Comment: Check again, it's showing 1 in the alert

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing data attributes with dataset JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66029026/accessing-data-attributes-with-dataset-javascript)

Comment: "1 is expected here" @TBA. It's in the last paragraph of the question.

Comment: @TBA I have checked again but localhost provides alert null, is it a browser issue ? why am I facing this problem?

Comment: @Andy it's showing his expected result only

Comment: Does the script appear before or after the DOM has loaded?

Comment: @TBA then what's the problem? Every data-area attribute has a value of 1.

Comment: @PoromaloyGrouP like andy is saying, check when you are calling your script

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit easier.

```
document.querySelector('#pickup option:checked').dataset.area
```

If we use `#pickup`, we selecting by ID as you have above.  But by also specifying `option:checked`, we're looking for the currently selected option.  (`:checked` is a bit weird here, but it's consistent with how other input elements work, such as checkboes.)  Next, if you want the `area` data option, we can access it on the `dataset` property directly.

Answer (score 0):

If nothing is selected, or the option does not contain the `data-area` property, your result will be not as expected.

It is generally [not a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871640/why-is-using-onclick-in-html-a-bad-practice) to use inline event handlers.
Here's a snippet using [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation).

```js
// => onclick="calculateDeliveryCharge()" becomes
document.addEventListener(`click`, handle);

function handle(evt) {
  if (evt.target.nodeName === `BUTTON`) {
    const selectr = document.querySelector("#pickup option:checked");
    // find the selected option using a css selector ^^^
    // this statement returns the option element when something 
    // is selected, null if nothing is selected
    console.clear();
    
    if (selectr && 
        selectr.dataset.area) {
      //        ^ a data attribute value can be found using the elements' "dataset"
      return console.log(`Area: ${selectr.dataset.area}`);
    }
    
    console.log(`No area or nothing selected yet`);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">
    <select id="pickup" placeholder="পিকআপ এলাকা নির্বাচন করুন">
      <option value="">পিকআপ এলাকা.....</option>
      <option value="300 Feet" data-area="1">৩০০ ফিট (300 Feet)</option>
      <option value="Adabor" data-area="1">আদাবর(Adabor)</option>
      <option value="Adarsha Nagar(Badda)" data-area="1">আদর্শ নগর(বাড্ডা)- Adarsha Nagar(Badda)</option>
      <option value="Aftab Nagar" data-area="1">আফতাব নগর(Aftab Nagar)</option>
      <option value="Aga Nagar" data-area="1">আগা নগর(Aga Nagar)</option>
      <option value="Agargaon" data-area="1">আগারগাঁও(Agargaon)</option>
      <option value="Ahalia-Uttara" data-area="1">আহালিয়া-উত্তরা(Ahalia-Uttara)</option>
      <option value="Ahmed Nagar" data-area="1">আহমেদ নগর(Ahmed Nagar)</option>
      <option value="Ainusbag" data-area="1">আইনুসবাগ(Ainusbag)</option>
      <option value="Ainusbag-Dakshinkhan" data-area="1">আইনুসবাগ-দক্ষিণখান(Ainusbag-Dakshinkhan)</option>
      <option value="Ajiz Market" data-area="1">আজিজ মার্কেট(Ajiz Market)</option>
      <option value="Alatunnessa School Road" data-area="1">আলাতুন্নেছা স্কুল রোড(Alatunnessa School Road)</option>
      <option value="Alubazar" data-area="1">আলুবাজার(Alubazar)</option>
      <option value="Amin bazar" data-area="1">আমিন বাজার(Amin bazar)</option>
      <option value="Apollo" data-area="1">অ্যাপোলো(Apollo)</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<button class="border-1 p-2 bg-danger text-white">ডেলিভারি চার্জ দেখুন</button>

</div>
```